# How to enable SQL logging in Aqueduct 3?

Tags: dart, aqueduct

It would be very useful for me to see in the terminal what requests are executed and how long they take.
Logging of HTTP requests works fine, but I did not find a similar function for SQL.
Is there a way to enable logging globally using `config.yaml` or in `prepare()` of ApplicationChannel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like i found dirty hack solution:

```
Future prepare() async {
  logger.onRecord.listen((rec) => print("$rec ${rec.error ?? ""} ${rec.stackTrace ?? ""}"));
  logger.parent.level = Level.FINE;
  ...
}
```

We need to set log level higher then default `INFO`. All SQL queries log their requests on `FINE` level.

I expected that this setting should be able to load from a `config.yaml`, but I did not find anything similar.

More about log levels can be find [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/logging/latest/logging/Level-class.html)

Comment: Yes, it’s currently not very configurable - if the logger level is fine or below, you’ll see your queries. See also this issue if you have ideas on how you’d like to control logging: https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/issues/447